# Mixed effect models - post hoc analysis - comparisions

Tags: r, mixed-model, post-hoc

I have some experimental data that I am trying to analyze. I will try to explain the data: I have three different reading tasks, in each one I have six blocks of presentation, and manipulated the length of the words (short and long). Children from two different grades made one of the tasks, and the items were the same for everyone. I have used mixed effect models, being the best model the following:

```
m15 = lmer(RT ~ GRADE* TASK * BLOCK* LENGTH+ (1|SUBJECT)+(1|ITEM), data= my.data)
```

After making an ANOVA of this model I got a significant interaction: `GRADE*TASK*LENGTH`. I want to do post hoc analysis in order to see how differ the length effect in the different tasks between the two grades. I have made the post hoc analysis:

```
lsmeans (m15, pairwise~GRADE*TASK*LENGTH, adjust="tukey")
```

But what I got were data comparing always short and long words (or short from one task with short from another, or the same with long). And I need to have a length effect measure (long - short words) for comparing along the task in each grade. Is there any R function to do that?

Sorry if it isn't very clear, I've tried to explain the best I could.

Comment: Sorry if this doesn't pertain exactly to your question but doing all pairwise comparisons is not the best way to follow-up an interaction (although it seems to be commonly done). Your 3-way means the Task x Length interaction differs as a function of grade. I would start by plotting and possible testing for significance these two-ways for each level of grade.

Comment: There are several contrast families supported besides `pairwise`. It sounds like you may want `revpairwise`? But are you sure you want to compare every factor combination with every other? Look at the documentation for `summary.ref.grid` -- you can specify restrictions using variables in `by`, or simply incorporate in the formula, e.g. `revpairwise ~ LENGTH*TASK | GRADE`